# Setting attributes with homemade classes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm quite new at rails and ruby so I'm not even sure if this is necessary, but I'm trying to add attributes to my model that are of one of my homemade classes.
In the tutorials I've read, the attributes are just listed after attr_accessible and the types of those attributes are not defined.  My question is: how do I define the type/class of an attribute or do I even have to?

Comment: Could you share some Code please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those types (String, Date, for example) are defined in your database...activerecord will read the attributes from your database.
You can read more [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/active-record-the-rails-database-bridge/), and can always use the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html)